# Batch-add watermarks with unique text for each picture

Tags: windows, images, image-processing, photography, digital-watermarking

I have over 500 pictures that I need to watermark with text that will be different for every image. For example, if I have a picture of a building I want to watermark the name or address of this building.

I have the unique information saved in an Excel file with the image file name.

Now after searching for the past three days I have not come across a tool that can batch watermark unique text for each picture.

I am primarily running on a Windows, and I am comfortable using command line to complete this process.  I am also willing to spend some money on a tool to do this so it doesn't need to be free and/or open source.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need a bit more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements at minimum: What OS or is a web-app acceptable? GUI only or CLI only or either?

Comment: Thanks, I should have done that before I posted. I originally posted this question on photo.stackexchange.com but that seemed to make some people upset over there.

Comment: @njackson.gis Not "upset". It was just the wrong place for it.

Comment: @mattdm i was not talking about your post. its the helpful one. I was referring to the other posts. I had seen a lot of question about watermarking and processing images on that site and that's why I decided to post there first. thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @njackson.gis Is reading the excel file a requirement or would you be okay to have to save that as a CSV or some other format?

Comment: @NickWilde excel is not a requirement. I was actually in the process of converting it to a simple text format so I could try to use it in ImageMagick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) convert command from a batch file it will allow you to apply text to a file, convert the type, rescale, etc., all in a single operation - it is also free.

e.g. `convert rose.jpg -draw  "text 25,60 'By Any Other Name'" outdir/rose.jpg`

Alternatively you could use [python](http://www.python.org), [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (the python image library) *or [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.5.1#downloads) (a fork of PIL)* and [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/) to do the whole job automatically including reading from the excel files.  These are also free tools but will take a little more learning on your part.
**I would strongly recommend taking a backup of all your images before trying any operations on them.**

## Updated:

Just to add - *seeing some of the comments on the original question* that **all** the tools that I mention in the answer above are:

- Free (Gratis)
- Free (Open Source)
- Cross platform, specifically:

  - **[ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/)** *command line graphics manipulation*:

    - Binary downloads for Unix, Mac OS(X), Windows & Linux
    - Source available so you can probably build it for just about anything else.
  - **[Python](http://www.python.org)** *Programming Language*:

    - Windows binaries available
    - Usually already installed on OS(S), Linux, Unix & many others
    - Ditto the source source
  - **[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)/[Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.5.1#downloads)** *Image Manipulation Library*:

    - Binaries available for Windows
    - Installed from source if you have Python/PIP on other platforms
  - **[XLRD](http://www.python-excel.org/)** *Python Excel Reader Library*

    - Source distribution works on any python platform

Comment: Steve this does the trick. I just converted my excel to .txt and then create a batch file to add the text. Thanks for pointing me to this software!

Comment: Gland to hear it worked for you @njackson.gis

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but I stumbled over this question 2 weeks ago and found a solution by doing some coding:

I managed to solve a similar issue with [bulkWaterMark](http://www.bulkwatermark.com) and .NET, where you can watermark dynamical text via a feature called expressions. I used the Freeware version of the tool and coded a custom expression context plug-in that loads data from an xml file where image informations are stored. Then I wrote an expression that takes the current image's filename as parameter and looks it up in the xml file - all done in C#.

The problem was that there is no SDK documentation available and I'm also not sure if this plug-in interface is officially public, but you just have to inherit 2 or 3 classes and override some methods to inject your own code into the application. It worked like a charm then.

You just need to reference the assembly PMlabs.GrfX.Framework and create your own implementation of these three classes:

```
 - ExpressionsPlugIn<TExpressionContext>
 - ExpressionContext
 - Expression<TExpressionContext>
```

The Expression class is the function that is called when an image gets rendered. The context holds multiple expressions and the plug-in class holds the context. Just make sure to implement everything in the abstract Expression class, the others are just plumbing code.

After compiling your plug-in assembly put it into the bin/plugins folder of your bulkWaterMark installation.

Another edit: Published a simplified code of my solution at Github today: https://github.com/barnacleboy/bulkWaterMarkExpressionPlugin